# document.body.getElementById is not a function

Tags: javascript

Happy New Year to all. Today, I encountered a very strange thing.

**TypeError: document.body.getElementById is not a function**

Several times I have checked all the characters, everything must be true

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function addElem()
        {
        var number=document.body.getElementById("number");
        }
        </script>
        <input type="text" id="number">
        <br>
        <button onclick="addElem()">Add</button>


 </body>
   </html>
```

Why do I get this error?

Comment: Because `document.body` doesn't have such a property. `document` has. [See the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById). Please check the documentation before you ask a question.

Comment: You could have used chrome dev console - intellisense would have displayed all the functions , attributes on the object

Comment: Why does this question have so many negative votes? This is a perfectly valid question to ask if one gets this TypeError.

Comment: The documentation doesn't have the error explicitly laid out, and this is first result on Google

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use  `document.getElementById()`  not `document.body.getElementById()` to achieve the desired effect

Answer (score 6):

That's because `document.body` is an element. Elements do not have a `getElementById()` method since ids are unique and using it relative to specific element would be useless.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a getElementById() method for the document.body element

Use document.getElementById() instead!